# OneLogin cookie is not being set in latest edge browser for windows

Tags: windows, microsoft-edge, onelogin

I have a ruby on rails project which redirects outside to another site A. I do indirect login to site A through API endpoint which returns set-cookie header in response. Browser should set this cookies, so when I redirect to site A, it considers user as logged in.

This is working fine on all other browsers but not working on windows Edge browser. I can see set-cookie in response header but it's not setting it up.

Note: Working fine on Mac version of Edge.

Response:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tatvb.jpg

Comment: Do you mean the same code not working on Windows Edge but working on Mac Edge? If this is the case, I think you can try to compare the versions and the settings of the Edge browsers in different OS, especially the settings of **Cookies and site permissions** to see if you have blocked the cookies. I think maybe the different browser environment settings result in the different behavior.

Comment: Have checked. Version and setting are same.

Comment: I suggest that you can provide [a minimal, reproducible code snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that we can test the issue. Besides, you can also contact OneLogin official or open an issue on [OneLogin GitHub](https://github.com/onelogin) as it also might be an issue with their product.